# Trying to convert iOS project using WinObjC, but getting missing sys/types.h error

Tags: winobjc

I'm running ....\bin\vsimporter.exe (with default settings) in my project folder and the .sln file seems to build successfully, but when I try running the simulator (on Win32 Solution Platforms, debug build), I get a bunch of errors. Most of the errors involve a missing file from the iOS 8.4 SDK (sys/types.h):

Error                     unknown argument: '-Xanalyzer'
Error                     'sys/types.h' file not found
Error                     unknown type name 'XSym'

Am I supposed to include the iOS8.4 SDK? Any help/suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I had the types.h problem too. Try to manually retarget to the Win 10 SDK:
Right-click on the solution and hit retarget, select the latest Win 10 SDK from the list, select all projects and click ok. The types.h problem should be gone.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That helped. Though, I'm faced with a much greater problem -- a number of frameworks in my project aren't supported yet and not sure Pods work with Bridge?

Comment: I think you should raise an other question for this one. As for the original question, I think it was fixed with this commit https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/commit/2d236ea858d0e655537d956a4719a3f0260ba388

Answer (score 0):

Retarget answer worked for me to get rid of the errors with missing header files.

To get rid of the -Xanalyzer issue, I removed it from the .vcxproj file as a command line option using a text editor.

For the pods, I manually copied them from a Mac that already had them downloaded.